# Kinect: Grab/Release

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, eventhandler

I'm a beginner in Kinect Programming. Yet I read different tutorials and texts about it. Furthermore I was working on the code examples ("Controls Basis-WPF").
Unfortunately none of the sources teach me how to code grabbing and releasing in a way that I understand.

I would like to create dynamically KinectTileButtons. While the program is running the user should be able to place the buttons to the positions he prefers. The player uses his hand as the cursor.
For example:
There is a button b1 on the top left corner. 
While the hand of the user is not on b1, the button doesn't change his position. 
If the user's hand is on the button AND he makes the "GRAB"-gesture, the position of the button is like the position of his hand (variable position). When he RELEASES, the position of button is constant and will not change until the user is grabbing for the button the next time.

I'm very thankful for any advices, suggestions or code examples, because I really don't know how I should continue to work on this problem.

Thanks in advance 
derpate

Answer (score 0):

What you should be going for is to change the location of the buttons on the window. I would have some global `bool`s to signify is they are grabbing and holding. Then I would put a conditional in the update to move the label to the position of the hand. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
bool grabbing = false;
bool selected = false;
var button;
var handElement;

Start()
{
    button = window.Button;
    handElement = window.handElement;
    ...
    sensor.Start();
}

Update() //all frames ready
{
    using (SkeletonFrame sf = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        ... //get skeleton and position

        ... //tell if grabbing
        if (/*however you do the grab gesture*/)
            grabbing = true;

        if (selected && grabbing)
        {
            button.X = handElement.X;
            button.Y = handElement.Y;
        }
    }
}

Button_OnClick()//or whatever it is called for the Kinect UI control
{
    selected = true;
}
```

Sorry for the pseudo-code, I just haven't worked with the Kinect UI before, and I didn't want to have half pseudo-code with the elements I don't know, however I know that it has events like `OnClick()` for when it is held, and I don't know what you mean by "GRAB" gesture but I assume you know how to implement it if you know what it is. Good luck!

Know also this only works for one button. If you were doing this for many, I would suggest a class... something like:

```
class MoveableButton : KinectButton//again, don't know the exact name of this
{
    private int X, Y;
    private bool selected = false, grabbing = false;

    public void Selected()
    {
        selected = true;
    }

    public void Grabbed()
    {
        grabbing = true;
    }

    public void LetGo()
    {
        grabbing = false;
        selected = false;
    }

    public void Update(UIElement hand)
    {
        if (selected && grabbing)
        {
            this.X = hand.X;
            this.Y = hand.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

This you would then call the appropriate methods during certain frames, I would have an array of them to loop through for `Update`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Currently the "GRABBING" is realised in `private void InteractionStreamOnInteractionFrameReady`...`if (hand.HandEventType == InteractionHandEventType.Grip)`. Unfortunately this isn't exactly enough, because there are severel "Grabs" and "Release" during one second. So I need a more precised solution, which seperates the the different states (normal, grab, release) exactly.

Comment: So any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3428544 That does complicate things

Comment: @user3428544 So the problem is that `InteractionHandEventType.Grip` is not accurate enough?

Comment: The eventtype is accurate enough but not the way it is fired up.

Comment: @user3428544 What do you mean?